# Magnetic field in the exterior of a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Consider a solenoid as shown in the picture attached.
[image]

I know that for an 'infinite' solenoid the field outside is supposed to be zero. I want to use the Right Hand Rule for currents and fields which states that if the thumb points in the direction of the current, the fingers of the right hand curl in the direction of the field. Using this, I get a non-zero contribution from each turn towards the right inside the solenoid.

However, similarly I also get a non-zero contribution towards the left, outside the solenoid. I am not sure why this is wrong, although I have read from multiple sources that the field outside is zero for an infinite solenoid, and the proof is normally using Ampere's Circuital law.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with applying this rule.

Comment: I don't know the answer, can only tell you that in an infinite solenoid the contribution to outward direction (both left and right) mutually superimpose and cancel each other. Being infinite there would be an element that would sum up to cancel the contribution

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://web.ua.es/docivis/magnet/solenoid.html%23:~:text%3DAn%2520intuitive%2520argument%2520can%2520also,see%2520Gauss%27s%2520law%2520for%2520magnetism).&ved=2ahUKEwiMyc6ewf_tAhVD6XMBHYHHBT4QFjAEegQIAhAE&usg=AOvVaw3znhPJFLh5oE9jcHn_ekxW&cshid=1609668430833.       -source of above two texts